# Unity3D: How to make an object always touch the map mesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

i am developing a racing game. But it's not your usual racing game, **the bike is supposted to always have the Y coordinate of the same value as the closest point on the map mesh**, in other words it is **ALWAYS** touching it.

What i *do not want* is the Y coordinate to be dependent upon the X and Y position, as there will be 2 (or maybe more floors).

I have absolutely no idea how to implement this. Completly zero. I am rather new to scripting, and this i way out of my league, i don't even know how to start... The map is not a simple plane, so simple maths won't help.

I'll apreaciate any help at all, not necessarily a solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you simulating physics?  If that's the case, just add a mesh collider to the ground and add a `Rigidbody` along with any collider(s) you feel are appropriate to the bike.

Comment: @Foggzie eI want to completly reject unity physics. No unity gravity. Actually no gravity at all for the bike. The unity physics are not needed for me, actually they are an obstacle, so i wan't to avoid them entirely. I have already used this "solution" before, but my problem is i don't want to use it. What i need is for the bike to always stick to the ground, and in no point in time be out of touch with it. If possible, i would avoid rigid bodies. I don't need any physics already provided in unity. Colliders are fine though.

Comment: Use Physics.Raycast to fire a ray from the bike's center to the ground.   The hit info it returns contains the distance along the ray that a collision occurred.  Move the bike by this amount.   Once you realize you also need to rotate the bike, you can do this using the collision normal that is in the hit info.

Comment: @LeoBartkus 's idea works just fine, but might I suggest using 2 raycasts from the bottom of the bike's wheels and using the 2 hits to position and rotate the bike instead? Using a single raycast from the bike's center might cause problems if the ground is uneven, like a crater for example

Comment: @Ryolu's solution will work perfectly for this case given that you don't want to use the built in physics simulations. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: @Ryolu I will try your solution once i finish designing my map. I'll post here how it went. Seems perfect. Simple, smart, easy. You can post this as an anwser if you would like. If not, i'll anwsere my question myself it this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea is an adapted version of @LeoBartkus's

I suggest using 2 raycasts from the bottom of the bike's wheels and using the 2 hits to position and rotate the bike. This allows for an accurate positioning of the bike for all kinds of terrain, except for spikes narrow and tall enough to appear to pierce the bike. Using a single raycast from the bike's center might cause problems if the ground is uneven, like a crater for example

Comment: Works very nice. For now i use only 1 raycast, because someone else from my team will take care of making the bike frontwards and backwards ( it will have to do with the bones of my bike model). Thanks a lot, this solution is very easy and it is effective.